# UML dependency or association in class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have class `Controller` in my java project, which has method like this:

[image]

As you can see, in the first line I am getting Singleton instance of `ActualModes` class and call method `getActualModes()`.

So the first question is, which relatinship I should use in class diagram.

After that I am creating new instane of `ModeContext` class and then call method `executeStrategy`. In this case, which relatiship is better ?

Comment: No relationship exists after the method returns, so neither is an association.

Comment: @M. Barabas: Please check one answer as accepted if you are satisfied, or explain why you are not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

[image]

Access to the singleton (note the stereotype which is just convenient and no obligation or general standard) is anonymous and so you just have a dependency. The `ModeContext` in contrast uses a private (I don't know the scoping rules of the language you used, so I made it pivate) property called `context`. Note the dot which is saying exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: UML does not specify a mapping between Java and UML, so every answer to your question is open for debate.

I think both relationships are *dependencies*, drawn as dashed arrows from `Controller` to `ActualModes` and from `Controller` to `ModeContext`. The definition of 'dependency' according to the UML 2.5 specification (§7.8.4.1) is:

> A Dependency is a Relationship that signifies that a single model Element or a set of model Elements requires other
>   model Elements for their specification or implementation.

An example of a type of relationship which is in my opinion *less* suited, is the *association*, although its definition (§11.5) is quite broad:

> An Association classifies a set of tuples representing links between typed instances. (...) An Association specifies a semantic relationship that can occur between typed instances.

One could argue that there are links between `Controller` and the other two classes, in the form of variables, but these variables are local method variables, which exist only temporarily during the execution of the method. Associations represent more durable links, e.g. class members - as far as I understand UML and as far as I have seen associations used in practice.